# Avoid Mutating JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Below is my code

```
let traces = { ref: null, min: null, max: null, avg: null };
let learning = {
    "Application": "b3",
    "t": [
        {
            "d": 2,
            "BinaryType": "Current"
        },
        {
            "d": 3,
            "BinaryType": "Max"
        },
        {
            "d": 4,
            "BinaryType": "Avg"
        },
        {
            "d": 5,
            "BinaryType": "Min"
        }
    ]
};

let traceArr = Object.assign([],learning.t);

traceArr.forEach(trace => {

    if (trace.BinaryType == 'Current') {            
        traces.ref = Object.assign({}, learning);   
        traces.ref.t = [];
        traces.ref.t.push(trace);
        traces.ref.t[0].BinaryType = 'Refeyrence';            
    }

    if (trace.BinaryType == 'Min') {           
        traces.min = Object.assign({}, learning);
        traces.min.t = [];
        traces.min.t.push(trace);            
    }

    if (trace.BinaryType == 'Max') {            
        traces.max = Object.assign({}, learning);
        traces.max.t = []
        traces.max.t.push(trace);            
    }

    if (trace.BinaryType == 'Avg') {            
        traces.avg = Object.assign({}, learning);
        traces.avg.t = [];
        traces.avg.t.push(trace);            
    }          
});

console.log("Output",traces);
console.log("Traces- Should be non mutated",traceArr);
console.log("Original",learning.t)
```

I assume that when I modify the content of the array, the content of the original (learning) object should not getting affected.

Two questions:

- I was assuming that traces.ref.t = []; should change the reference in the new created object. Does it not?
- The console.log("Original",learning.t) output is as below which
  indicates that the content got changed (text **Refeyrence** which was
  modified during array iteration). Why is this happening? And what
  should I be doing to avoid it?

  'Original'
  [
      {
          d: 2 ,
          BinaryType: "**Refeyrence**"
      },
      {
          d: 3 ,
          BinaryType: "Max"
      },
      {
          d: 4 ,
          BinaryType: "Avg"
      },
      {
          d: 5 ,
          BinaryType: "Min"
          }
  ]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're having two issues, but both with mutateing a shared object.

> I was assuming that traces.ref.t = []; should change the reference in the new created object. Does it not?

Doing `[]` will create a new array instance, but `traces.ref` is still using the shared `traces` object at the very start. You likely want to create a copy of the `traces` object. Since it doesn't have any nested values, using spread syntax is an easy way to achieve that in your case:

```js
const newTrace = { ...traces }
```

> The console.log("Original",learning.t) output is as below which indicates that the content got changed (text Refeyrence which was modified during array iteration). Why is this happening? And what should I be doing to avoid it?

This one is because the `trace` object is being pushed into the array and then it's being modified. You can work around this by also using an object spread to create a shallow copy:

```js
newTrace.ref.t.push({ ...trace });
```

With only these changes, you original code may look like this:

```js
let traces = { ref: null, min: null, max: null, avg: null };
let learning = {
  Application: "b3",
  t: [
    {
      d: 2,
      BinaryType: "Current"
    },
    {
      d: 3,
      BinaryType: "Max"
    },
    {
      d: 4,
      BinaryType: "Avg"
    },
    {
      d: 5,
      BinaryType: "Min"
    }
  ]
};

let traceArr = Object.assign([], learning.t);

traceArr.forEach(trace => {
  if (trace.BinaryType == "Current") {
    const newTrace = { ...traces };
    newTrace.ref = Object.assign({}, learning);
    newTrace.ref.t = [];
    newTrace.ref.t.push({ ...trace });
    newTrace.ref.t[0].BinaryType = "Refeyrence";
  }

  if (trace.BinaryType == "Min") {
    const newTrace = { ...traces };
    newTrace.min = Object.assign({}, learning);
    newTrace.min.t = [];
    newTrace.min.t.push({ ...trace });
  }

  if (trace.BinaryType == "Max") {
    const newTrace = { ...traces };
    newTrace.max = Object.assign({}, learning);
    newTrace.max.t = [];
    newTrace.max.t.push({ ...trace });
  }

  if (trace.BinaryType == "Avg") {
    const newTrace = { ...traces };
    newTrace.avg = Object.assign({}, learning);
    newTrace.avg.t = [];
    newTrace.avg.t.push({ ...trace });
  }
});

console.log("Output", traces);
console.log("Traces- Should be non mutated", traceArr);
console.log("Original", learning.t);
```

[Here is this code in the TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/DYUwLgBGBOCGDGIDOEC8EDeFogGYC4IA7AV2GABoIBbASyMNPKutgA9GzKJYA3Ac07kIAXwDcAKFCRQsaEXr80mCRAgBBAA6bgteLDC0A9gwgAiAEYBmMxVVRCAbXtqMLtRAAmhAEx2PHgBC9HIAngAqoZoghGYAwiTQOERgZu4i-h5uAWreEFaZAcFEYZHRsQCy7GkBGe7ZOXkALIVBIdARUTHm6gI1HnUBDQF5AKytasWlXZX0-Woi9gC6EuISUuBQcIjqScoA8hYAViDwYAB0sEhItPxEABSOS1Sy8ornYACUkhIwCCC7aDnXBGaAAUQQAAt7n9EGgAHwqNS0XAQGHbEDnKYdMogNDoeKJZKpT5IjzwExISBEEAAd3CGOUWHOLNhyFEkgCNPpGPOOFR6EOJzOl2utweGAyEFeCiI-G+7m5DP+fLwH2UT05HiVvP5H3OmhISGhzNZjJECq5dOViFVuA+jgADEsse1OtFlGYAEp4EChZKIMxaxb2FFotmuko4rr48wVOak4YQClEKnEa2M9Cmj4YlBrK08lV0IgHY6nC5XG53e6Sl4gOSy+VatQ6ov0dXoTWKjNtoj6w3GmsQFk5-6iS2idbI1HolXY9141AEqpsMyJ9wptOtuFZ4dm-555vpwu21hsUvCiti6u16X1t5yictnun9gdiBdgs2zFn-tGk17qOcIWsGU4QGGs62vOuKxmYvT8GuZJqJu1IvoumCAWyh7diemJ8EogpliKlbijWUoyooT7Ht+lwCO+n7amhtH8H+g7Zmy46gSB6ybkYoDnMARj8PcZj7CQYCGqkVBYQqvH8YJwlmN+SAALQQAAypCRhkJ4EAWHiRAmDQ4kGCAni2Fs-yArJlJ8ZiCkifs0C3CEwAWRRcofAqQA). It contains a few type errors but this is the minimum number of changes to avoid mutations.

Comment: const newTrace = { ...traces } will not help. I want traces.min.t = []  statement to help me stop referring to the old object and suggest traces.min.t  to start referring this new Array. Else how do you change references in javascript? Remember I have a traces.min = Object.assign({}, learning); before I change the reference. So I am dealing with a brand new object anyways ( shallow copy)

Comment: It's not clear to me what the desired out come is. Could you provide what you expect the last 3 console logs to print you in your question? You can also do `traces.ref = { ...learning, t: [] }`. Currently, you're doing `Object.assign({}, learning);` but that's a shallow copy (same as `{ ...learning }`) so `t` will still be the same array instance but doing `{ ...learning, t: [] }` will create a new empty array instance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Object.assign() does a deep copy. I'm pretty sure it's creating a new array whose elements point to the original array. The simplest way to do a deep copy is to convert it to json and back.

```
let traceArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(learning.t));
```

The big disadvantage there is that if whatever you're copying has circular references, it won't work.

EDIT:

To illustrate what's happening, the learning object starts off as

```
let learning = {
    "Application": "b3",
    "t": [Object1, Object2, ...]
}
```

Then this happens,

```
let traceArr = Object.assign([], learning.t);
```

Which creates a new array and copies the contents of learning.t into it. At this point, traceArr looks like

```
traceArr = [Object1, Object2, ...]
```

Then, it loops over the items in traceArr, which are the same objects from learning.t, just pointed to from a different array.

```
if (trace.BinaryType == 'Current') {            
    // At this point, trace === Object1

    // Shallow copy of learning
    traces.ref = Object.assign({}, learning);
    // traces.ref = { "Application": "b3", "t": [Object1, Object2, ...] }

    // Create a new array for traces.ref.t
    traces.ref.t = [];
    // traces.ref = { "Application": "b3", "t": [] }

    // Adds Object1 (same object from learning.t) to the new array
    traces.ref.t.push(trace);
    // traces.ref = { "Application": "b3", "t": [Object1] }

    // Modify Object1
    traces.ref.t[0].BinaryType = 'Refeyrence';            
}
```

If you don't want traces.ret.t's elements to point to the same objects as learning.t, you need to create new objects, i.e. you need to push a copy of trace instead of trace. Or, as I suggested, make traceArr a deep copy of learning.t so that all the objects are new and nothing is shared.

Comment: Why can't I initialize an empty array? That's the easiest option for me and then add elements to it?

Comment: You can do that, but it adds references to the elements, it doesn't make copies. Since the array has objects, you need to do a deep copy of the objects. If the array was primitives, like strings or integers, the shallow copy would be good enough.

Comment: I updated my answer to hopefully better illustrate what is going on and why you need to do a deep copy of the learning.t array.